# How does git blame determine who edited a line of a file?

Tags: git, version-control, blame

Using

```
git blame file
```

will show all info about each line, for example who add this line in which commit, and when, but as far as I know, Git will add a completely new object every time you change a file.  So where does Git store such info about each line?

Comment: @Cupcake thanks for your revision, I will read this link until I never make the same mistake http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17607784/revisions

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself William, the question just needed a little cleanup. Trust me, I've seen questions that were far, far worse :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @mvp said, "it doesn't".  To answer your comment though—that is, "the flow of this process"—it works very roughly like a series of `git diff`s, starting with the most recent version of the file, and working backwards until every line has an assigned origin.

Suppose you have a short file with just four lines, and it is the most recent (i.e., the version in `HEAD`).  Suppose further that `git diff` shows that in revision `HEAD~1` there were only the first three lines, and I added that last (fourth) line.  Then the "blame" for line 4 would be mine: it was not there in the previous version, and it was there in the current, so I must have added it.

That leaves the problem of figuring out who to "blame" for those three lines.  So now git must diff `HEAD~1` against `HEAD~2`.  If those three lines all appear exactly as is in `HEAD~2`—which might be the case if, for instance, the change from `HEAD~2` to `HEAD~1` was simply to delete some lines—then we must keep going further back in history.

At some point, though, `git diff` will show that *someone* added line 1, line 2, and/or line 3 (in some previous version), possibly while deleting some other line(s); or in the worst case, git will reach a "root commit": a commit with no parents.  In any case, whoever committed the commit(s) that caused those lines to appear, must be the one to blame.

Answer (score 3):

> Where does Git store such info about each line?

Git does NOT store this info anywhere, at least not explicitly. Every time you run `git blame file`, this info is dynamically computed from objects stored in git object store. If you are interested in knowing how exactly this is done, you can read git [blame.c source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/blame.c).

Comment: so march code and in C, I just know a little Ruby, can you summarize that code with human readable description? like this: first it read this info from this object, and that info from that object, and add them together, and wallah!, you get that you want! I don't want to know the low level details, just the flow of this process